# Why does ArrayBlockingQueue use arrays for interior buffer removal?

Tags: java, queue

ArrayBlockingQueue contains a buffer as an array. It also supports the admittedly inefficient

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

> Removal of interior elements in circular array based queues is an
>   intrinsically slow and disruptive operation, so should be undertaken
>   only in exceptional circumstances, ideally only when the queue is
>   known not to be accessible by other threads.

Why did the designers use an array over a LinkedList here if I'm told LinkedLists are faster for removing elements from the middle of an array. Here is my theory:

Removals are mostly done from the Head, and maybe even tail, but rarely the middle. So the designers wanted to handle the more common use case and make that faster, therefore accepting the performance hit on the less common mid-buffer removal use case.

Comment: Because normally you don't remove elements from the middle of a queue.

Comment: "more common" doesn't do it justice. Mid-queue removal comprises at most 0.0001% of all operations done on `ArrayBlockingQueue` worldwide. But even without that, asking "why the designers used an array in an `ArrayBlockingQueue`" is pure nonsense. Maybe you wanted to ask "why did the designers ever bother implementing an `ArrayBlockingQueue`"?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the name: the `ArrayBlockingQueue` uses an array as buffer, a `LinkedBlockingQueue` uses a linked list.

There are some implementation differences:

The `ArrayBlockingQueue` uses a fixed size array to build a ring buffer to store the elements, it has therefore a fixed size that cannot change (but also a fixed memory overhead).

The `LinkedBlockingQueue` uses a linked list, so can basically grow as necessary, but has to do memory allocation on adding elements.

On the less common `remove(Object)` call both of them have to scan for the object (and have therefore O(n) time complexity).

Comment: I need to implement a Thread safe Bounded Queue. This issue is, the consumers of the queue can remove an element they're interested in even if it's in the middle. So I'm looking for a data structure for the buffer. Array is mid-array removal inefficient - but it's bounded. LinkedList is more mid-collection efficient but not bounded.

Comment: @TheCoder the `LinkedBlockingQueue` has a constructor `LinkedBlockingQueue(int capacity)` that allows you to define the maximum capacity.

Comment: @annotThomas K - I cannot use predefined data structures. I want to write my own.

Comment: @TheCoder if you write your own LinkedList implementation then there is nothing that prevents you from writing `while (capacity-size() == 0) wait_until_element_removed();` on each path that can add an object and `notify_element_removed();` on each path that removes an object.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayBlockingQueue uses an array because... well... it's an **Array**BlockingQueue, not a LinkedBlockingQueue.

If you want a linked-list implementation then use [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

Apart from that, you already have the answer: people very rarely want to remove something from the middle of a queue, so if you never do that, you can get the other advantages of the circular array implementation. If this is not suitable for your application then use a different implementation of BlockingQueue.